# access table object outside SQLAlchemy db session

Tags: python, mysql, transactions, sqlalchemy

I have the following code snippet to operates on the table Customer:

```
with session.begin(subtransactions=True):
    db_obj = Customer(...)

result = io_processing() # may cause greenlet switching

# I do not want to make it inside the transaction above,
# Because some legacy I/O related code which will causes greenlet switching
if result:
    self.read_write_db(session, db_obj)
```

In read_write_db function:

```
with session.begin(subtransactions=True):
    # do some work on db_obj passed from outside
```

Is it safe to pass 'db_obj' outside of the transaction into another function?

Or I have to query the db_obj again in the read_write_db and update it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you will have to get a new instance by merging `db_obj` in `read_write_db`'s session.

```
with session.begin(subtransactions=True):
    merged_db_obj = session.merge(db_obj)
    # work with merged_db_obj ...
```

See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#merging for all the details. Merging can be tricky.